# Packaging ASP.Net Application for Elastic Beanstalk Using Jenkins

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, jenkins, msbuild, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've set up my Jenkins server, and am able to build my solution (with multiple deploy-able projects in it) properly. Now, I'm trying to get everything in a project ready to deploy on Elastic Beanstalk, but it seems like I'm missing something such that when it gets "deployed", it is deployed such that my old code is still running.

I've tried searching around for anything to tell me how the AWS Toolkit plugin works, but haven't found a good breakdown on what it does when deploying. If anyone has an idea on all the steps it takes, I'd love to hear it. It seems like it's using MSDeploy in some way before zipping, but I don't know how to replicate the plugin's results using the command line.

Credentials are fine and all, I can go into the console and see that it's "updating" the instances, which is why I believe my problems are in my packaging.

Plugins being used:

MSBuild - http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin

AWS Elastic Beanstalk - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin

Configurations:

MSBuild file - SOLUTION_FILE

MSBuild Command Line Arguments - /property:Configuration=AWS-Staging /property:Platform="Any CPU" /clp:ErrorsOnly

AWS EB Packaging Root Directory - PROJECT_DIRECTORY\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - Add /t:Package to my MSBuild parameters